# "С легким паром"

Tags: фразеология

"Каждый год 31 декабря мы с друзьями ходим в баню..."
На Руси принято было поздравлять человека, вышедшего из бани, говоря ему "С легким паром!"
А почему вообще надо поздравлять того, кто помылся (у нас все-таки не Европа, где раньше вообще не мылись, так что не такой уж знаменательное событие)))), да еще такими словами. Если пар легкий, значит, предполагается, что есть еще и тяжелый?
Моя версия: речь о баньке "по-белому" и "по-черному".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, существует два полярных состояния затопленной бани, а именно: здоровая, бодрящая атмосфера, называемая "лёгкий пар» и «тяжёлый пар» — тяжёлая, гнетущая, удушающая атмосфера. Вероятней всего, последнее, создавалось не намеренно, а являлось делом случая. Соответственно, поход в баню мог быть как приятным, так и отягощающим. Поэтому, человека, который попал на "лёгкий пар", поздравляли с удачным посещением бани фразой "с лёгким паром". Отсюда же ноги растут и у пожелания лёгкого пара, человеку, который только собирается в баню.

Answer (score 3):

Есть такое объяснение. В банях пар мог смешиваться с угарным газом, от которого люди нередко угорали. Именно этот пар, в отличие от легкого, хорошего, считали тяжелым.

Из словаря: А. Кирсанова "Толковый словарь крылатых выражений".

Answer (score 1):

Ага, есть любители плескать всякой гадостью на каменку, типа настоек. Раньше хорошим таким квасом плескали, а то и пивом, что в принципе одно и тоже. Выходишь--полоумным,  в пол тянет, от ума большого. Нынче дураков много, еще и эвкалиптом на спирту--вперед шведские львы. Вот этот дурдом и есть тяжелый пар. Русскую, даже по-черному баню, всегда проветривают, угли из-пода каменки выгребают до последнего. Никакого УГАРА, кроме как от поддачи там не бывает в принципе.
Знай и люби русскую, по-черному, баню.